# unable to restart my server using node server/index.js

Tags: node.js, server

I am trying to run the server using :

```
node server/index.js
```

But I am getting this :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token >
at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

The index .js file is failing on :

```
db.each("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", (err, data) => {
    tables.push(data.name);
});
```

Any idea what may be wrong ?

Comment: which node version do you use?

Comment: [Arrow functions are supported in Node 4.x and later.](http://node.green/#arrow-functions) It seems you might be using an older version.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
db.each("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", (err, data) => {
tables.push(data.name);});
```

with

```
db.each("SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'", function(err, data) {
tables.push(data.name);});
```

as it seems your node version is not supporting this syntax.